# How to display the names instead of pk in the list viewset in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've designed an API to add songs and create a playlist.

models.py:

```
class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=400)
    artist = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=400)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title} by {self.artist}"

class Playlist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=100)
    songs = models.ManyToManyField('Song', blank=True, related_name='playlists')
```

serializers.py:

```
class SongSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Song
        fields = ['title', 'artist']
        extra_kwargs = {'playlists': {'required':False}}

class PlaylistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Playlist
        fields = ['name', 'songs']
        extra_kwargs = {'songs':{'required':False}}
```

views.py:

```
class SongViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Song.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SongSerializer


class PlaylistViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Playlist.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PlaylistSerializer
```

But when I do a get request on the Playlist, I get the results as the following:

```
{
    "name": "Classic Hits",
    "songs": [
        1,
        3,
        4
    ]
}
```

I want the songs' names to be displayed instead of their PKs in the playlist.How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

As you did not specify how `Songs` are deserialized in `Playlist`, the primary keys are returned. You could try:

```
class PlaylistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    songs = SongSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Playlist
        fields = ['name', 'songs']
        extra_kwargs = {'songs':{'required':False}}
```

For create/update on nested objects:

`By default nested serializers are read-only. If you want to support write-operations to a nested serializer field you'll need to create create() and/or update() methods in order to explicitly specify how the child relationships should be saved.`

You can modify the PlayListSerializer's create/update method:

```
class PlaylistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    songs = SongSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Playlist
        fields = ['name', 'songs']
        extra_kwargs = {'songs':{'required':False}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        songs_data = validated_data.pop('songs')
        playlist = Playlist.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for song_data in song_data:
            Song.objects.create(**song_data)
        return playlist
```

---

Refer to nested relationships in the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships).

Comment: This worked, however it doesn't allow me now to create a new playlist by giving the pk of the songs in the songs field. Everytime I create a new playlist now, the songs field is an empty list.

Comment: Tried that as well, still didn't help as it is trying to parse the pk values into the songs fields, and throws a non_field error.

Comment: I see. I updated the answer. Do read the documentation as it very well documented. You will need another method for `update`.